# Solaris FTP client implementation

Tags: java, ftp, solaris, ftp-client

I have FTP server written in java. No implementation of calculating speed.

But when I use Solaris FTP client or winSCP and connect to my ftp server and transfer file, it shows speed at the end like :

```
380352 bytes sent in 0.72 seconds (51562.34 Kbytes/s)
```

Can anybody help to let me know how this speed calculation is implemented. Or even guide where should I start looking.

Comment: you do realize that the ftp clients will KNOW how much data they've sent/received? e.g. you wake up in the back seat of a car and don't know where you've been, but after watching for a few minutes you'll know how fast the car's driving. You'll note they can't estimate the transfer time, because that'd require knowing how big the file they're downloading is.

Comment: but on the same note, server should also be knowing how much they have transferred or received. Then why don't server implement this functionality?

Comment: it's not the server's job to tell the client how fast/slow things are going. and yes, normally a server SHOULD know how big the file it's sending is, but it's not required information. e.g. a webserver dynamically building a pdf or a zip won't know how big the file is because the file's being constructed and sent out on the wire on-the-fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of the code in netkit-ftp that transfers a file, showing how it calculates the transfer rate.

```
recvrequest(...)
{
    volatile off_t bytes = 0;
    struct timeval start, stop;

    gettimeofday(&start, (struct timezone *)0);
    while ((c = read(fileno(din), buf, bufsize)) > 0) {
        if ((d = write(fileno(fout), buf, c)) != c)
            break;      
        bytes += c;
    }
    gettimeofday(&stop, (struct timezone *)0);
    ptransfer("received", bytes, &start, &stop); 
}

ptransfer(const char *direction, off_t bytes,
    const struct timeval *t0,
    const struct timeval *t1)
{
    struct timeval td;
    float s, bs;

    tvsub(&td, t1, t0);
    s = td.tv_sec + (td.tv_usec / 1000000.);
#define nz(x)   ((x) == 0 ? 1 : (x))
    bs = bytes / nz(s);
    printf("%jd bytes %s in %.2f secs (%.1f kB/s)\n",
        (intmax_t) bytes, direction, s, bs / 1024.0);
}
```

The steps are:

- store current time in `start`
- read from the net, write to the file, tallying up the byte count in `bytes`
- store current time in `stop`
- call `ptransfer`, which finds the difference between `start` and `stop`, converts it to a floating-point number, makes sure the time difference is not zero, then divides `bytes` by the time difference and prints the result in kilobytes per second.